# My question is being rejected for "quality standard"

Tags: support

I tried to post a riddle I created onto the site but is gave me and error saying that the body "does not meet quality standards"

**This is the full message:**

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

How can I fix my riddle so it meets these requirements? Thanks.

---

**The post goes like this:**

At first I heard it and thought i could soar like a bird!

And oh what i heard!

I’ll zoom so fast, my image will be blurred.

And now I see it, it’s flat as can be!

Oh woe is me.

And how lonely, just one single tree.

---

What is this riddle referring to?

Comment: Can you include the text of the riddle you're trying to post?

Comment: ^vote with a note: My positive vote indicates agreement that this riddle fits in with hundreds (but fewer than 1,478 at last count) of others that haven't been officially rejected.

Comment: I managed to resolve this by typing some junk sentences at the start and then editing them out.

Comment: Just a speculation:  Perhaps the failure to capitalize the word "I" is part of the reason it was deemed low quality?

Comment: I'd guess that it was a combination of the lowercase 'i', exclamation points and perhaps short sentences.  I got this error when trying to post [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31630/a-riddle-i-places-b4-u), which I then had to work around by using the questionable technique of putting the whole riddle in MathJax.